# EditText onTextChanged ,Search in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, search, android-edittext

In my project I have an EditText. 
When I enter text to EditText, onTextChanged function it search the entered text to sqlite and show the search list.It is Ok, but the problem is in BackSpace.It search until one char in EditText.Then, if no char in EditText i want to show the original List(ListView).How can i do or catch event for backspacing on char in EditText(Reset ListView) condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can catch event from afterTextchanged

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                          if(s.length()==0)
                          {
                               //Code here 
                              //reset your ListView adapter
                          }
                    }
```

i hope this code will work for you

Comment: Thanks @Htoo Aung Hlaing